# How to read values into ArrayList without breaking Functional Programming principles?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm talking about Functional Programming on Java. Let's say I have an ArrayList and want to input a few values. The problem is that I can't think a way to do it that doesn't break the principles of the paradigm. So far I can guess that I should replace iteration with recursive functions, but what about passing the input value to the array? If I do something like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And then:

```
MyArrayList.add(in.NextDouble( ) );
```

I am actually using a variable, so I guess this solution isn't acceptable. Same if I try to use JOptionPane to get the input, because I have to convert the string to number and that requires the use of a variable. Is there a way to input values from the keyboard to an ArrayList without involving variables or loops? If not, what's the standard practice in FP when facing a case like this? Just turning a blind eye and breaking the principle this once?

Comment: Why would you want to?  Do the simplest thing that works and is maintainable.   If you have to jump through hoops to maintain a paradigm, then it probably isn't the right one.

Comment: @GabeSechan Because of homework. I agree that this is overdoing it and I also know that there are better languages for functional programming, but I don't get to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to get 10 `double` values from the `Scanner`.

You can then use [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/):

```
List<Double> myArrayList = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(i -> in.nextDouble())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As [commented by shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682969/how-to-read-values-into-arraylist-without-breaking-functional-programming-princi/49683052#comment86377802_49683052), this might be a better way:

```
List<Double> myArrayList = DoubleStream
        .generate(in::nextDouble)
        .limit(10)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you want a primitive array, simply:

```
double[] myArrayList = DoubleStream.generate(in::nextDouble).limit(10).toArray();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Now, if you *truly* want to do functional programming in Java, you shouldn't be using the mutable collections in the Java Runtime Library. Instead, look for a functional programming library, such as [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io/):

> Vavr core is a functional library for Java. It helps to reduce the amount of code and to increase the robustness. A first step towards functional programming is to start thinking in immutable values. **Vavr provides immutable collections** and the necessary functions and control structures to operate on these values. The results are beautiful and just work.

*Disclaimer: I don't know Vavr. Have no need for pure functional programing in Java in my current work.*

Comment: If I actually saw that code in a production pull, I'd not only reject it, I'd be talking to my manager about the guy writing it.  Do you know how many temporary objects, how many allocations, and how much work you're doing for such a simple task?

Comment: @GabeSechan Yeah, I know. This is not about performance. It's about the purity of **functional programming** in a non-functional language, which doesn't even have tail-recursion optimization. If you write "functional" code in Java, with tail recursion to get around immutability constraints, you end up with StackOverflowErrors. If you care about performance in Java, you wouldn't insist on "functional". If you insist on "functional", you wouldn't write it in Java.

Comment: Or `DoubleStream.generate(in::nextDouble).limit(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, just for fun and maybe of some theoretical interest:

```
try (Stream<String> tokens = new Scanner(System.in).tokens()) {

    List<Double> list = tokens.takeWhile(t -> !"-".equals(t))
            .map(Double::parseDouble)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

This reads tokens from the standard input until a hyphen is read, parses them to `Double` instances and collects the doubles to a list.